# How can I use PowerShell to delete files and parent folders in a specific directory based on last modified date?

Tags: powershell

I would like to create powershell script to delete files and folder with this scenario :

- parse all items is E:\Data\Report
- In Report Folder, I have a lot of folder like "1578, "1579,"1576" etc.
- Each folder has many files
- My script have to read every folder and subfolder and fine files where last modification is up to 30j
- then delete files
- then delete parent folder "1578" if it's empty
- etc

But i'm stuck because I can't find how to return to parent folder.

Here is my script for now, could you help me please ?

```
$folderPath = "E:\Data\Report"
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)

Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath -Directory | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

My code pasted here only delete file but not parent folders

My main folder is GLASSART, my script need to parse every subfolder (209580,209581,209582 etc), each one has files and sub folder

[image: my folder organisation]

Answer (score 0):

Note: Based on later feedback and the update to your question, you seem to be looking for use case 2 below.

**Use case 1:**  If the **subfolders of `$folderPath` contain only *files*** (and not also subfolders of their own):

```bash
$folderPath = "E:\Data\Report"
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)

Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $folderPath -Directory | 
  ForEach-Object {
    # Determine which files inside the folder at hand should be deleted, 
    # and which should be kept.
    $toDelete, $toKeep = 
      ($_ | Get-ChildItem -File -Force).
      Where({ $_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit }, 'Split')
    # No files to keep? Delete the folder at hand as a whole.
    if (-not $toKeep) { 
      $_ | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -WhatIf
    } 
    # Should a subset of the files be deleted?
    elseif ($toDelete) {
      $toDelete | Remove-Item -Force -WhatIf
    }
    # Otherwise: no files to delete.
  }
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#-whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf` and re-execute once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

---

**Use case 2:** if too-old files and then-empty subfolders must be deleted from the **entire subtree** of each subfolder.

Note:

- To be safe, `-WhatIf` has been left in place in the first `Remove-Item` call below. However, this means that the *folder*-deletion aspect of the solution cannot be previewed, given that the logic would only kick in if the files and subfolders were actually deleted. In other words: you'll only be able to preview what *files* would be deleted.
- By *not* using `-WhatIf` in the folder-deletion `Remove-Item` call, any *already empty* subdirectories are removed right away.

```bash
$folderPath = "E:\Data\Report"
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)

Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $folderPath -Directory | 
  ForEach-Object {

    # Step 1: In the entire *subtree* of the subfolder at hand,
    #         delete all too-old files.
    $_ | Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Force | 
        Where-Object LastWriteTime -lt $limit |
        Remove-Item -Force -WhatIf

    # Step 2: Examine all folders in the subtree, including the subfolder at hand,
    #         starting at the lowest level, 
    #         and iteratively delete any (now) empty folders.
    & { $_; $_ | Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory -Force } |
        Sort-Object -Descending { ($_.FullName -split '[\\/]').Count } |
        ForEach-Object {
          # Is this folder (now) empty?
          if (-not ($_ | Get-ChildItem -Force | Select-Object -First 1)) {
            $_ | Remove-Item # Remove this folder
          }
        }
  }
```

Comment: Hello,  thank you for your information.
I have tried the script : it always delete the folder (whatiff) , no matter the date .

I also found something with Get-Item instead of Get-ChildItem, but I can't loop and find LastWriteTime foreach subfolders.

Comment: @BenjaminDerepas, it deletes the folder only if either there are no files in the folder at all or if _all_ of them are older than `$limit`.  By design, it never looks a the _folder's_ last write time - is that a requirement, and how does it factor into your task?

Comment: I add folder organization in attachment for more visibility .

I have justed tested the code on a backup folder : **every** folder (209850 etc) were removed. It seems it doesn't care about threasold time, I don't know why, any idee please ?

Comment: @BenjaminDerepas, _recursive_ processing requires a different approach. Please see my update (use case 2).